# Attempting to send an HTML PUT request via Guzzle. Getting back a '400 Bad Request'

Tags: put, guzzle, jira-rest-api

So I am currently attempting to use the JIRA api to update an issue by sending it an HTML request via Guzzle. The code that I am using to do that is:

```
$response = $cGuzzel->request('PUT',$strJiraAPI, ['headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
    'auth' => [JIRA_USER, JIRA_PASS],

    [
        'update' => [
            'fixVersion' => [
                'set' => [
                    'name' => $strTag
                ]
            ]
        ]

    ]]);
```

I am getting back the following error: "errorMessages":["No content to map to Object due to end of input"]. I understand that there is something wrong with my request. However, after looking through examples and documentation, I'm still not totally sure what that is.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put your data in some named container (`'json'`, `'form_params'` or simply `'body'`). In your case it seems to be `'json'`, which automatically adds proper Content-Type.

```
$response = $cGuzzel->request('PUT', $strJiraAPI, [
    'auth' => [JIRA_USER, JIRA_PASS],
    'json' => [
        'update' => [
            'fixVersion' => [
                'set' => [
                    'name' => $strTag
                ]
            ]
        ]

    ]
]);
```